# How to POST json file/data to api url via python

Tags: python, json, api, csv

Sorry if this question simple for you guyz but I still have no solution for it. I need your help here.
I have json file with the data that need to be post to DB via api. The post request return response 200 (ok) but the data is actually not store to the DB.

Please find the code that i use to send the json data to api url

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.1:7279/ctrl/api/topodisco'
headers = {'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 
'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=open('elements.json', 'rb'), headers=headers)
print(r)
```

This is the content of elements.json file

```
[
  {
    "type": "rtr-x",
    "name": "we-01",
    "ip": "1.1.1.1",
    "location": "jbx"
  },
  {
    "type": "swr-x",
    "name": "sw-03",
    "ip": "172.16.3.18",
    "location": "jbx"
  },
  {
    "type": "rtr-x",
    "name": "we-03",
    "ip": "1.1.1.10",
    "location": "jbx"
  }
]
```

This is sample of api body that shall be followed

```
{
  "service": "topodisco",
  "action": "create_node",
  "table": "user3",
  "node": [
    {
      "type": "SAMPLE_TYPE",
      "name": "SAMPLE Name",
      "ip": "192.1.1.1",
      "location": "sample location"
    },
    {
      "type": "SAMPLE_TYPE",
      "name": "SAMPLE Name",
      "ip": "192.1.1.2",
      "location": "sample location"
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking into that, I don't know how to insert service,action,table and node onto the script. Is there a way that I can add those to the code above without modified/edit the json file. The json file is generated from a csv file. Please help me.

Please advise me further. Thank you for your attention and support

Comment: You may wish to post the code behind your endpoint `/ctrl/api/topodisco` as that is likely where the issue is, not with the data itself.

Comment: Hi, may i know which code are you referring?  http://192.168.1.1:7279/ctrl/api/topodisco is the request url that was provided to me. Data that I have in json shall be send to this url with the body specified above.

Comment: How can you debug the insertion of data into the database if you don't have access to the code that does the insertion?